# Plsql wont insert because of duplicate records

Tags: plsql

So I am trying to fill a table that connect two different tables by randomly selection the id from a products table x amounts of time and then putting this id together with an id of the shops table. And then repeating this for all id from the shopa table. This way every shop gets a random amount of products; However because sometimes my randomly selected ID is the same as an id that is already in the Table for example

shop = 1 ||product =34

shop = 1 || product =20

shop = 1 || product =34

How can i prevent this from happening the code that i am trying to execute is

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE GENERATEPRODUCTS
 AS
 PRODUCTTEMP NUMBER;
 NROFPRODUCTS NUMBER;--total number of available products
 NROFWINKELS NUMBER;--total number of shops
 MAXNROFPRODUCT NUMBER;-- the maximum amount of products to be inserted
 PRODUCTPERCENTAGEZONDER NUMBER;-- random percentage that will be added to 90%
 PRODUCTPERCENTAGEMET NUMBER;-- total percentage of to be inserted products
 WINKELS NUMBER;--counter for looping through shops
 PRODUCTIDTEMP NUMBER;--the id of the product that needs to be inserted
 BEGIN
 PRODUCTIDTEMP :=1;
 WINKELS := 1;
 PRODUCTPERCENTAGEMET :=0;
 PRODUCTPERCENTAGEZONDER := 0;
 select count(ID)
 into NROFWINKELS
 FROM WINKEL;
 select count(ID)
 into NrofWinkels
 FROM WINKEL;
 select count(ID)
 into NROFPRODUCTS
 FROM PRODUCT;
 select DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,10) into PRODUCTPERCENTAGEZONDER FROM DUAL;
 PRODUCTPERCENTAGEMET := (90+PRODUCTPERCENTAGEZONDER)*.010;
 MAXNROFPRODUCT:=ROUND(NROFPRODUCTS*PRODUCTPERCENTAGEMET);
 WHILE WINKELS <= NROFWINKELS
 LOOP
 WHILE MAXNROFPRODUCT<=NROFPRODUCTS
 LOOP 
 SELECT ID
 INTO PRODUCTTEMP
 FROM(
 SELECT ID
 FROM PRODUCT
 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
 WHERE ROWNUM=1;
 INSERT INTO WINKEL_COUPON
 ("ID",WINKEL_ID,COUPON_ID)
 VALUES
 (PRODUCTIDTEMP,WINKELS,PRODUCTTEMP);
 PRODUCTIDTEMP := PRODUCTIDTEMP+1;
 END LOOP;
 WINKELS := WINKELS+1;
 END LOOP;
 END;
```

In this code i want that every shop gets atleast 90% of the available products;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put a CONSTRAINT on the table.

That way you can make sure that some columns have a unique value in them. 
For example, if you want the value for ColumnShop and ColumnProduct together to be unique in the table you have to put a contstraint on the table that looks something like this:

```
CONSTRAINT <NameTheConstraint> PRIMARY KEY(Shop, Product)
```

By doing this, the table will only accept values to be inserted in the table that are unique. 
So Shop = 1, Product = 34 will be inserted if that combination doesn't exist yet. If it does it will atomaticly raise an error that a constraint has been violated.